# asp.net textbox doesn't have clientmode attribute

Tags: asp.net

If I declare a DIV and set it to runat server I get a clientmode attribute which I can set to determine what the ID comes out to be on the rendered page. I need to do this for a drop down and a textbox but clientmode isn't available on those controls.

What can I do? I don't want to do some crazy workaround. If it comes to it i'll just do an auto postback and do what I need there.

Comment: Are you talking about ClientIDMode? If so, it is available for both WebControls and HTMLControls. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

Comment: No, it isn't. Only if you're using ASP.NET 4. I should have clarified I am using 3.5. Good to know when I'm doing an ASP.NET 4 project.

Comment: Prior to .NET 4.0 this property is not available at all. Not even for HTMLControls. So this attribute would render as is without having any impact on the ID itself in case of div with runat="server" i.e. the ID of the div would be controlled by framework itself.

Comment: @amit_g ClientMode attribute. Just not on all controls.

Comment: @DustinDavis would you be kind enough to provide a link to this in msdn or anywhere else or may be an example? Sorry, I must be missing something trivial and it keeps bothering me :)

Comment: GAH! I'm an idiot, it IS clientidmode but it isn't available on all controls. I have a DIV tag for example that has clientidmode but the textbox doesn't have it (at least doesn't expose it in intellisense). I'm using asp.net 3.5

Comment: @DustinDavis, check the rendered code. I did a little test and even though VS2010 IntelliSense does show this attribute but since the framework doesn't support it, it is rendered as is without having any effect on ID attribute.

Comment: @amit LOL! Oh well. It was meant for the CSS designers but I guess they will need to figure something else out... Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DropDownLists and TextBoxes have a ClientID attribute that tells you the client-side ids of the rendered HTML elements.

Comment: I would rather have clientmode but i'll take this. Thanks.